# (How) can I make weak references to proxy objects act like weak references to the proxied objects?

Tags: c#, weak-references

As part of some IPC framework, the server-side code implements a mapping of integers to objects (such that IPC messages can use integers to reference objects).

The mapping doesn't store references straight to the objects though but to `IGUIObject` implementations, an interface to be implemented by proxy objects which wrap the actual objects. I.e. there's an interface like

```
interface IGUIObject
{
    Rectangle Bounds { get; }
}
```

and then possible implementations like

```
class WindowsFormsControl : IGUIObject
{
    private Control m_control;

    public WindowsFormsControl( Control control )
    {
        m_control = control;
    }

    public virtual Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            return m_control.Bounds;
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping class, a singleton, looks like this:

```
class ObjectDict
{
    private static readonly ObjectDict s_instance = new ObjectDict();
    private Dictionary<int, IGUIObject> m_idToObjectDict;
    private Dictionary<IGUIObject, int> m_objectToIdDict;
    private int m_lastObjectId;

    public static ObjectDict Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return s_instance;
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public IGUIObject objectForId( int id )
    {
        IGUIObject go;
        if ( m_idToObjectDict.TryGetValue( id, out go ) ) {
            return go;
        }
        return null;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public int idForObject( IGUIObject go )
    {
        // Lookup ID for objects, register object and return new ID if needed
    }

    // ...
}
```

The problem with this is that the `ObjectDict` class should not keep the application objects from being garbage collected, i.e. it should hold weak references and in such cases `ObjectDict.objectForId` should throw an exception.

Alas,

- holding weak references on the `IGUIObject` implementations doesn't seem to help, because the `ObjectDict` class *is* the owner of the wrapper objects. There's no other place where they are stored. The wrapper objects only get removed from the dictionaries if the IPC system receives an explicit 'release object with ID 12345' message. The issue I need to solve though is that it may be that the proxied object is garbage collected and I want to allow, detect and handle it gracefully. The wrapper objects should live as long as the proxied objects (potentially longer), but no shorter.
- making `WindowsFormsExtension` hold a weak reference to the `Control` object and then making `ObjectCache` hold a weak reference to the `IGUIObject` implementation doesn't help either, because the proxy object (i.e. `WindowsFormsControl`) doesn't mirror the "null-ness" of the contained object. Another complicating factor is that there are many (a couple dozen) implementations of the `IGUIObject` interface, but only a single `ObjectDict` class. So any solution which does not require me to do the tedious and error-prone job of adjusting all `IGUIObject` implementations to start using weak references would be much preferred.

Does anybody know how to adjust the code such that `ObjectDict` does not (indirectly) hold strong references on any objects wrapped by `IGUIObject` implementations?

Comment: `holding weak references on the IGUIObject implementations...` Why would that not work? If the wrapper is unreachable so is the proxied object.

Comment: @usr I didn't think that to the end, I'm afraid. The `ObjectDict` *is* the owner of the wrapper objects, i.e. it cannot hold weak references to them. The wrapper objects are always there for as long as the IPC system doesn't explicitly send a 'release' message to remove them from the dictionaries. However, it can happen that the proxied object goes away already (it should certainly be allowed to do so!) and I want to handle that situation gracefully.

Comment: So basically you want to be able to destroy proxied objects, always keep the wrapper alive and prevent destruction while the wrapper is in use? How is "in use" defined?

Comment: Why don't you make the dictionary a `Dictionary<int, WeakReference<IGUIObject>>`?

Comment: @usr Right, the lifetime of the proxied objects should not be changed at all. I do not want to prevent destruction of them in any way. The wrapper objects however - I don't care so much actually (they are very small). I just need to notice when the objects they wrap are no longer there so that I can handle this situation. It just occurred to me that I'd like my wrapper objects to behave like weak references, which made me bring this term up. I.e. the wrapper object should live at least as long as the proxied object, potentially longer - but certainly no shorter.

Comment: So shouldn't the wrapper object use weak references for the proxied object then?

Comment: @Groo That sounds like the idea which I considered (and dismissed) in my first bullet, no?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Right - that sounds a lot like what I sketched (and dismissed) in my second bullet. The issue with that is that I need to propagate the information that the proxied object went away somehow, and there are a lot of `IGUIObject` implementations which would need adjustment.

Comment: So you basically have an object implementing `IGUIObject`, that may be collected. You also want a lot other code to use the object through `IGUIObject`, but not prevent collection? Is that it? If so then I believe the answer provided by @usr should fit the bill.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: If the actual control (proxied object) is being shown, i.e. as a part of a certain message loop, it cannot be collected. I don't really understand the functional difference between GCing the wrapper and GCing the actual instance? If the control is collected, what use is the wrapper for? (as a side note, using a `ConcurrentDictionary` should provide lower contention than `lock(this)`, and I am presuming `ObjectDict` has a private ctor too)

Comment: Well, basically rather than storying dictionary of objects we could obtain data dynamically by observing some other collection and copying its values using `ToDictionary()` method. This will create no references and allow original objects to be collected by GC *in the same time* allowing to access them. Not sure if it is possible to implement or not but this might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add another layer of abstraction :)

```
class WeakGUIObject : IGUIObject
{
    WeakReference wr;

    public WindowsFormsControl( IGUIObject inner )
    {
        wr = new WR(inner);
    }

    public virtual Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            var inner = wr.Target;
            if (inner == null) throw ObjectDisposedException();
            return inner.Bounds;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can make the dictionary reference and hand out `WeakGUIObject` instances. This automatically makes all proxied objects weak.

Not sure this whole design is a good idea. Clients of `ObjectDict` might find that their objects disappear at random times and start throwing. But that seems to be what you are aiming at.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! Indeed, the design means that objects can go at any time. However, this whole code is part of a debugging utility which is merely meant to 'monitor' the application, i.e. it readily acknowledges that things may disappear. The primary goal is to not influence the monitored application too much.

Comment: Alas, I'm not sure if this will fly: with this design, we *only* keep weak references to the proxy objects, i.e. there's nothing which speaks against GC'ing them immediately. The net effect would be that we consider the real object to be disposed even though it's happily alive: it's just the `IGUIObject` wrapper which got destroyed. Maybe if there was a way to tell the GC to link the lifetimes of the `IGUIObject` wrapper and the proxied object such that the wrapper object will live as long as the real object (which also brings me back to the question title)...

Comment: You can use `ConditionalWeakTable` to link object lifetimes. You could add an item (realObject, proxy) to it. That keeps the proxy alive exactly as long as realObject is live.

Comment: Indeed, but alas I also need to support .NET 3 at this point. I think if I could find a simple way to establish a 'back-reference' from the wrapped object (e.g. some `Control`) to the wrapper (e.g. `WindowsFormsControl`), then that would be perfect: the two would be coupled as far as the lifetime goes.

Comment: Maybe if I just setup an event listener (which doesn't actually do anything) such that the `Control` object *needs* to hold a reference to the wrapper.

Comment: Why not use a field? `object keepAlive;`.

Comment: I cannot add fields since I don't control the wrapped class, e.g. Control.

Comment: You can misuse Control.Tag if it's not already in use. Otherwise, you could indeed use CWT. Or, a dummy event indeed :)